# Compile and link library at once in CMake

Tags: cmake, git-submodules, cmake-modules, makefile

I'm new in CMake enviroment. I have this project-structure tree:

```
/my_proj
│ 
├── deps
│   └── my_dep
│       └── CMakeLists.txt
├── src
│   └── main.cpp
└── CMakeLists.txt
```

Where **my_dep** is a git submodule used as dependency for **my_proj** project.

Usually I compile separatly these two entities, compiling first the library *my_dep* and then linking it to *my_proj* exe.

```
cd my_proj/deps/my_dep
cmake . && make

...compiling library...

cd my_proj
cmake . && make

...compiling exe and linking the above lib...
```

Now I would like be able to compile both library than executable in **once**, with a single CMake command.

The **/my_proj/CMakeList.txt** file must contaign all needed commands to first compile the **my_dep** lib and generate the *.a/.so file*, and after this compile the **my_proj** *exe* and finaly link the lib with exe.

I want make this procedure in **once**, with only a make command, e.g.

```
cd my_proj
cmake . && make

...compile lib, compile exe and link lib to exe...
```

Can you give me a simple explanantion about make it possible?

Comment: Compiling a library and linking with it should be described in almost any CMake tutorial. Have you checked one of them? E.g. that one: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/Adding%20a%20Library.html

Comment: Use `add_subdirectory`; This doesn't satisfy the requirements as described, but it's most likely what you want. Of course the submodule needs to be initialized (unless you want cmake to do this during configuration). If you do `add_subdirectory(deps/my_dep)` in the toplevel `CMakeLists.txt`, the targets in `deps/my_dep/CMakeLists.txt` should be available to link via `target_link_libraries`... Btw: you won't be able to use a single cmake command to configure&build; those are 2 separate commands the second one replacing `make` in your snippet (`cmake . && cmake --build .`)

Comment: Btw: it's preferrable not to set up the source dir as build dir. Especially when using a repository this will save you time, since you avoid having to write `.gitignore` files; instead from the directory containing `my_proj` do something like this: `mkdir my_proj_build && cmake -S my_proj -B my_proj_build && cmake --build my_proj_build`; the last command can be replaced with `cd my_proj_build && make` if you want to use `make` directly.